# Django query: the last Mail received grouped by Conversations

Tags: python, django

My Model:

```
class Mail(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    message = models.TextField()
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='receiver', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='sender', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sent_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    conversation = models.ForeignKey(Conversation, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

My query:

```
Conversation.objects.filter(mail__receiver=request.user).annotate(latest_msg=Max('mail__id')).values('id','mail__id','mail__subject','mail__message','mail__sender__username','mail__sent_date','mail__read').order_by('-latest_msg')
```

It returns all the Conversations which contains any Mail received by the logged user (request.user). Why? I want the last message received grouped by Conversations, like Gmail.

Edited:
Here's the native query:

```
Query: SELECT "app_conversation"."id", "app_mail"."id", "app_mail"."subject", "app_mail"."message", T6."username", "app_mail"."sent_date", "app_mail"."read" FROM "app_conversation" INNER JOIN "app_mail" ON ("app_conversation"."id" = "app_mail"."conversation_id") INNER JOIN "app_user" T6 ON ("app_mail"."sender_id" = T6."id") WHERE "app_mail"."receiver_id" = 1 GROUP BY "app_conversation"."id", "app_conversation"."owner_id", "app_conversation"."user_id", "app_conversation"."create_date", "app_conversation"."archived", "app_mail"."id", "app_mail"."subject", "app_mail"."message", T6."username", "app_mail"."sent_date", "app_mail"."read" ORDER BY MAX("app_mail"."id") DESC
```

Comment: Well you here make an assumption that the `id` is in creation order, which does not always holds *per se*.

Comment: The ID always is incremental. Anyway, it returns the same result with `mail__sent_date`

Comment: can you add the sql query corresponds to the orm by, `print((Conversation.objects.filter(mail__r..........).query)` ?

Comment: Added the native query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. Here is the query:

```
maxMailsIds = Conversation.objects.filter(mail__receiver=user).annotate(maxId=Max('mail__id')).values_list('maxId', flat=True)
items = Mail.objects.filter(id__in=maxMailsIds).order_by('-id').values('subject','message')
```